# Confusion about the objective function of VQEs and QAOAs

Tags: quantum-algorithms, vqe, optimization, qaoa, state-tomography

I am a bit puzzled on how the objective function of the VQEs and QAOAs. Of course, the parametrised state is constructed differently in these two algorithms but they do share a common objective to be minimised, specifically:

$$
\mathrm{min}_{\phi} ~ \langle \psi_\phi | H |\psi_\phi\rangle
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $|\psi_\phi\rangle$ the state that the quantum circuit prepares. One then, usually makes $N$ measurements and obtains a set
$$
\{ h_1, h_2, \ldots,h_N \}
$$
which correspond to the **empirical estimates of the expectation value** $\langle \psi_\phi | H |\psi_\phi\rangle$.  I read in the literarue that one can use these to formulate the **sample mean**
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N h_i(\phi)
$$
and feed this to the classical minimiser.

**Confusion**: although I do agree that the sample mean above indeed samples the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, I cannot see how one practically implements this into the classical optimiser!

Specifically, the set of measurements $\{ h_1, h_2, \ldots,h_N \}$ is the output of some quantum process tomography procedure and **they must correspond to real numbers** and not functions of the parameters $\phi$.

**How one can convert the sample mean, which is the average of real numbers $\{ h_1, h_2, \ldots,h_N \}$ to a function of the parameters $\phi$?**

Comment: The cost function is actually a function of $|\psi(\phi)\rangle$, which is generated by some unitary operator $U(\theta)$ (a parametrized quantum circuit). Explicitly,we can write it down as: $C(|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle) = \langle \psi(\vec{\phi})|H|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle$. It is bounded.  So we want to varies $|\psi(\phi)\rangle$ (by changing the parameter $\phi$ in the quantum circuit) such that the value of the cost function tends toward its minimum.

Comment: Given a specific $|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle$,  you can't calculate $  \langle \psi(\vec{\phi})|H|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle$ directly on a quantum computer. What we need to do is to decompose $H$ into linear combinations of Pauli strings, $H = \sum \alpha_i P_i$ then calculate $  \langle \psi(\vec{\phi})|H|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle$  as $ \sum \alpha_i \langle \psi(\vec{\phi})|P_i|\psi(\vec{\phi})\rangle$. Note that each $P_i$ is a Hermitian and Unitary operator, hence it has eigenvalue of $\pm 1$. So you can use sample mean to determine its expectation easily. So these $h_i$ are just $\pm 1$.

Comment: The frequency that you observe $+1$ or $-1$ is of course depending on $|\psi(\vec{\phi}) \rangle$, and this frequency is tie back to the expectation $\langle H \rangle$. So yes, the measurements $h_i$ is indeed related directly to the parameter $\vec{\phi}$ since $\vec{\phi}$ determines what the wavefunction $|\psi(\vec{\phi}) \rangle$ is.

Comment: This is clearly written in the preliminary part of the question. I basically ask, given a value for the sample mean, sums of the $h_i$ over $N$, what is the precise classical optimization problem?

Comment: Make that value as low as possible.